# Approximation lemma for continuous functions $f\in C_{K}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove the next proposition:

Suppose that $f\in C_K$ has support in the compact interval $[a, b].$ Given any dense subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists an
$A-$valued step function $f_{\epsilon}$ on $(a, b)$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)-f_{\epsilon}(x)|\leq\epsilon.$$

I'm stuck. I was thinking in use Stone-Weiestrass Theorem, so there is a sequence of polynomials $\{P_{n}\}$ such that $P_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x) uniformly.$ I'd like to built a $A-$step function utilizing the convergence of polynomials such that  $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)-f_{\epsilon}(x)|\leq\epsilon,$ but I don't get it.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Use the uniform continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$, $A\subset \mathbb R$ and $\varepsilon>0$ be as above.
Since $f$ is defined on a compact, it is uniformly continuous, so we can find a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x,y\in[a,b]$ we have
$$|x-y|\leq\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\frac \varepsilon2.$$

Now subdivide the interval $[a,b]$ into pieces
$$[a,a+\delta)\cup [a+\delta, a+2\delta)\cup [a+2\delta,a+3\delta) \cup \dots \cup [a+n\delta, b],$$
where $n$ is the largest natural number with $a+n\delta\geq b$.

Now we define $f_\varepsilon$ to be constant on each piece $I_i:=[a+i\delta,a+(i+1)\delta)$ with value $\alpha_i\in A$ chosen such that $|f(a+i\delta)-\alpha_i|<\frac\varepsilon 2$ (this exists because A is dense in $\mathbb R$).

Now it is easy to calculate that for every $x\in I_i$ we have (using $|x-(a+i\delta)|\leq \delta$):
$$|f(x)-f_\varepsilon(x)|=|f(x)-f(\alpha_i)|<|f(x)-f(a+i\delta)|+|f(a+i\delta)-\alpha_i|< \frac\varepsilon 2+\frac\varepsilon 2=\epsilon.$$

Hence we conclude that
$$\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-f_{\epsilon}(x)|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: Nice proof @Tashi Walde! Thank you.